# How should I compute the integral $\int \frac{\arcsin x \, dx}{x}$?

Tags: integration

I don't know how to integrate $\frac{\arcsin x}{x}$, when I integrate by parts I get the same result.

Comment: afaik there is no antiderivative in elementary functions

Comment: http://goo.gl/RY7CR0

Comment: What do you mean by "you get the same result?"

Comment: Are you aware of the polylogarithm function?

Answer (score 1):

Gradsteyn-Ryzhik section 2.83 says clearly that there is not answer in terms of a finite combination of elementary functions. So the integral is in in real applications done by series expansion $$\arcsin(x)=x+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{3}{40}x^5+\frac{5}{112}x^7\ldots$$